# Instantiate a ViewModel with parameters from another one

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to instantiate a SecondViewModel from a MainViewModel injecting in this second one paramaters that are services registered in the IoCContainer and objects from the MainVM.

The code is something of this kind:

```
class MainViewModel
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    private string message = "the message";
    public string Message { get; set; }

}

class SecondViewModel
{

    public SecondViewModel(IService service, string message)
    {
    }

}
```

now, i know i can make the IoC Container inject a SecondViewModelFactory (that carries the service instance) into the MainViewModel, so it can create the SVM through it, but what if the implementation of IService is very heavy and i don't want to instantiate it but when i really need it.

And what if i have to instantiate other ViewModels in a similar way? Do I have to create tons of VMFactories and constructor's parameters?

And in case I use a generic ViewModelFactory, it would need to be instantiated passing all the services needed by every ViewModel I have, regardless if they will be created or not.

Do you know any better solution to my case?

Thank you guys

Comment: Don't pass the ÌService` into the second view model, rather let the second view model resolve the `IService`-instance from the IoC-container...

Comment: but I have to pass a MainVM's property/field into the SecondVM's constructor. How do you achieve this making the SecondVM resolved by the container?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought this was mainly about passing that `IService`-instance... There seems to be no way round the service model factory in that case...